# Angular 8 router - loading wrong component

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular8

I am working on this example:

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-app-example-wtpacb)

When runs it first shows navbar:

```
Home    Settings
```

But when I select either Home or Settings I get the same navbar shown again and it looks like this now:

```
Home    Settings
   Home    Settings
```

Also when I reload by clicking on Reload icon I dont get previously selected route selected again.

Please help me with these problems.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had to create routers for child routes: Home and Settings. check the example again.